# Where to store information about executed Contentful migrations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-migration, contentful

So our Contentful-based application has grown a little bit and we have to create content migrations for new features etc. And to prevent executing the same migration multiple times we think we must store info about executed migrations - but where?

My choices are:

1. External database (`Sql`/`NoSql` - doesn't matter which type)
2. List of executed migration on code repo
3. Tagging repo after successful migration? (`migrations/1-blog-post`)
4. Some other way?

Which do you think would be the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've created a fork of the contentful migration tool that stores this information in a content type inside the space.
https://github.com/watermarkchurch/contentful-migration

This works great for our rails apps, we store migrations in the `db/migrate` directory alongside our rails migrations.